# Releasing the port COM14 in windows

Tags: windows-xp, serial-port

I have an application with it executable installer and it tries to install the driver on port COM14 but when I check the list of ports I found that COM14 port is already occupied by some other app and that why current application is not being able to install the driver on COM14.

Please advise how to release the port COM14 in windows XP.

EDIT: Now I am looking at going with following url: http://blog.cognitioninfotech.com/2009/01/how-to-clear-or-reset-com-port.html

Comment: Adjusted tags. No apparent TCP aspect to this question.

Comment: @Rocky, is this an application that you are writing?